# Set checked checkbox from array

Tags: php, html, checkbox, selected

I have 2 set of array which represent all data and selected data

```
$all_data = ["admin","member","editor"];
$selected = ["admin","member"];
```

I want to make all list of data that have checked if $all_data value = $selected value
What the best method to make it possible?

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Comment: it's unclear what are trying to do. "I want to make all list of data" , `$all_data` is already "all list of data". Or clarify your question with expected result(output)

Comment: I just solved my problem , i loop $selected inside $all_data and give condition if val of $all_data == $selected.  Thanks all , sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code -

```
<?php
$all_data = ["admin","member","editor"];
$selected = ["admin","member"];

foreach($all_data as $value) {
  $checked = in_array($value, $selected) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="' . $value .'" ' . $checked . '>';
}
?>
```